# Can my MacBook Pro use a large 30" LCD monitor

Tags: macbook, lcd

I have a MacBookPro 3,1 with an NVIDIA GeForce 8600M GT w/ 256MB RAM. I have only one DVI port.

Can I run one the new large 30" LCD monitors from Apple or Dell? If not, is there some kind of adapter I can get that will allow me to?

I run my MBP closed attached to a 20" LCD monitor when working at home. My current monity (6 yrs old) is just too small these days.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hold up people with your answers.

He said its a Macbook Pro 3,1 which is the older body style with one dvi port.  This is not the newer unibody with mini display port.

All you need to hook up to a 30 inch display is a dual link dvi cable.  That is all, no adapter is needed with that model. It supports the 30 inch models from dell or apple(apple's monitors just have a built in cable).

Also, apples 20 and 30 inch monitor are dvi based monitors and the 24 inch LED one is the one that uses the mini display port.

http://store.apple.com/us/product/M9179LL/A?fnode=MTY1NDA5OQ&mco=MjE0NTg4OA

Dell sells two 30 inch LCD's and they have a few different options:
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Monitors/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=222-7175

http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/products/Monitors/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=223-4890

I use the exact setup you have with the dell 2709W 27 inch and it works great. I love Dell's Ultrasharp LCD lineup.

http://reviews.cnet.com/4520-10442_7-6470175-1.html  apple 30 vs dell 30

Comment: Thanks for the added information on Dell, I've been looking at those since I find the Apple prices to be a little out of line.

Comment: I added a link to a review for you.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes, with the right adapter

The newer Apple Cinema Display are actually made for the new unibody MacBooks and MacBookPros.  They have a Mag safe and mini display port cable built in so that you can reduce cable clutter.

Comment: So are you saying that I could get a Mini-display to DVI adapter and plug the Cinema Display into my non-unibody MBP?

Comment: How old is the Cinema Display?  If it is not the newest 24" one (from late 2008) it should have a DVI port on it already.  See what your monitors have, and get the necessary adapter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the one DVI port is referring to the MacBook Pro: The Dell monitor should come with a DVI cable (or at least they used to) and the new Apple 30" displays should work if you purchase the Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter ([found here](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB570Z/A)). However, you should note that the DVI supported on the adapter is DVI-D (digital only).

Comment: I forgot there is no DisplayPort enabled 30". Ignore the adapter comment.